# Is existed web markup languages with possibility insert sql query?

Tags: database, ms-access, jsp, dhtml

Actually what I want - simple DB with simple User Interface. Like MS Access, but for web and it can be without Dragn n Drop, but described with markup language.
For example if I want to create list report, then i need to write something like:
`<table query="SELECT * from mytable"></table>`
It needed for simple data applications. In that kind application no programming logic required. Just working with DB. Changing DB data and showing it.

Comment: `<table query="DELETE * FROM mytable"></table>` - i.e. very bad idea!

Comment: That technology can be only server side and access to markup file has only priveleged person. Therefore no one outside can damage database.

Comment: The MS-ACCESS tag adds nothing here, as the question has zilch to do with Access, except as point of comparison.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The nearest solution I found at that moment - use [ZK framework](http://www.zkoss.org).
Disadvantage - I must create JPA beans and DAO, but on other side - I do not need to create data structure directly in DB.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Cold Fusion supports SQL queries in CFML pages.
There are also open-source implementations like Railo.

Java Server Faces also supports the SQL tag library in the core set.
Every implementation supports it, but open-source Apache Cocoon extends it providing unmatched features.

Answer (score -1):

Access 2010 allows you to use the same development process you always used. And, you get forms, sub-forms, continues forms and really nice reports. You don't have to know any HTML or see any kind of Markup language.

And, while you can do a lot without any coding, the code that you do write inside of a form does results in that coding running INSIDE of the web browser on the users desktop (it converted to JavaScript). So the resulting applications respond very well to user inputs and often do so without a round trip to the server.

Here is a video of an application I done using the new access Web features. Note how at the half way mark in the video I switch to running the application 100% in the browser.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI

Comment: I think it is great solution, but not for me. I think that it will run only on Windows machine (maybe Mac), but i need to host it on Linux. But it was interesting to know about that ability.

Comment: Well the resulting web site does not use Silverlight or any ActiveX. I tested those web sites built using ms-access using Ubuntu running the Firefox browser and they rendered perfect. So, the user does not care about what browser. I also tested them using my iPad. So, the results are browser netural.

Comment: I care not about browser, but about server where that web application will be hosted.